# Android returns error "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to boolean"

Tags: java, android

I got these kind of error messages based on my code.

Code

```
if (mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces)) myAudioFunc();
```

Error messages

```
Error:(195, 43) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to boolean
Error:(195, 59) error: cannot find symbol method myAudioFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not exactly sure what "mNativeDetector" is, but a little bit of googling suggests that it's this: https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-3.1.0/classorg_1_1opencv_1_1samples_1_1facedetect_1_1DetectionBasedTracker.html

If that's the case, then your problem is really simple (and in the error message itself). `detect (Mat imageGray, MatOfRect faces)` is type `void` which does not return anything. So first, you're trying to run a condition based on `if (void)`, which is invalid and causes your first error.

Then you compound the issue by calling `myAudioFunc()`, which gives you:
`Error:(195, 59) error: cannot find symbol method myAudioFunc()`

That second error says that you haven't declared `myAudioFunc()` anywhere yet.

What you would normally do is hook up a callback or listener to an `onDetect()` function, but I can't seem to find one given my limited googling. For an operation like `detect`, it's possible that it won't return immediately, so even if you could make your code work this way, you probably wouldn't want to as you'd hang while detection does its thing--and that could take a long time.

I hope that helps.